# Typical food in Norway?

Tags: food-and-drink, restaurants, norway, local-cuisine

I'm going to Norway (Bergen) soon and I want to taste something typical from that nation or from Bergen's region.

I was thinking that one of the most typical food was fish, but I'm not sure about it.

Which is a typical Norwegian food?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE and hopefully our answers here will be better suited to a question like this than on cooking.SE.  I removed the second question about where to eat, as it's much more of a recommendation request/solicitation (see our [faq]) but hope that our answers at least satisfy your main question about Norwegian food!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traditional Norwegian dishes are usually based on fish and game. Given that Bergen is a port town, I suspect that there are some stellar restaurants that specialize in seafood.

Here are a few restaurants that showed up on several sites as highly-rated; I browsed through the menus and they looked good, also:

- Potetkjelleren Restaurant (http://www.potetkjelleren.no)
- Boha Restuarant (http://www.boha.no)
- Enhjorningen Fiske Restaurant (http://www.enhjorningen.no)

Happy eating!

Comment: Have you been to any of these?

Answer (score 8):

Arguably, the national dish of Norway can be considered to be [Fårikål](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A5rik%C3%A5l) - "sheep in cabbage" - pieces of mutton with bone, cabbage, whole black pepper and often a little wheat flour, cooked for several hours in a casserole, traditionally served with potatoes boiled in their jackets.

In tradition, Norway's foods come from the natural food resources available in their country - largely game and fish.

More recently they've been influenced by continental Europe and America - and indeed, you can find almost any food in most large Norwegian cities.

But you're after typical food to try, and presumably you don't mean the common pizza or pastas :)

Seafood is something you're going to want to hit up first - especially salmon.  Smoked salmon from Norway is now a major export and comes in many forms - try gravlaks (buried or pit salmon) - traditionally salted and buried to ferment.

In recent years - shellfish, trout and mussels are more common as well.

Meat and game - you'll want to try moose, reindeer, mountain hare, duck, foul and lamb (especially aged lamb or mutton used in the afore-mentioned fårikål).

Kjøttkaker (meat cakes) and Kjøttboller (meal balls) are also quite common everywhere.

If you want some non-meat food stuffs, try grovbrød (or coarse bread) - common at breakfast and lunch.  You'll often see it with the common Jarlsberg cheese or gammalost (old cheese).  Dairy products in general are extremely popular still in Norway.

Hopefully that's enough to whet your appetite.  For more ideas, suggestions and alternatives, have a look at the [Wikipedia article on Norweigan cuisine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_cuisine).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what has been mentioned above, a typical Norwegian delicacy that is definitely not found in other countries with the exception of perhaps Iceland & Japan is Whale or as is termed in english "Whale Beef".

A typical recipe for a such a dish maybe found here:

http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2002/08/13/eating_whale_steak.html